Smart contract wallet
About smart contract wallet, it is not only smart contract but also a wallet, may i know how does it support programmability ? how to define customized  rules and conditions,  I had searched many in internet , but almost just high level explanation, would you pls share me one concrete solution and guideline about it ? Thank you

Your question is not pointed . Are you referencing  https://www.erc4337.io/docs .

I are referencing circle programmable wallet and erc 4337. I see they just mention abstract gas fee etc, but not mentioned programmability, how to define rules and conditions.
